# When mc runs as root doesn't obey bindings

Tags: midnight-commander

I created a `bindings` file for `mc` that opens `geeqie` file viewer when my user presses `Enter` on a `[jJ][pP][gG]` file.

Copied that `bindings` file from `~./config/mc/bindings` to `/root/.config/mc/`.  When I start `mc` as `root` and press `Enter` in a `.jpg` file, `mc` opens `gimp` and not `geeqie` as is in the `bindings` file.
After reading the manual, it seems that for recent versions of `mc` this kind of information is saved in a `mc.keymap` file, but starting `mc -K /root/.config/mc/mc.keymap` as root still opens `gimp` instead of `geeqie` when trying to view a `jpg` file.

What am I missing?  Why is the behavior different when starting `mc` as `root` than as `myuser`?

```
$ mc -V
GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.16
```

in a linux box